# Co-authorship network edge list for igraph R

Tags: r, matrix, networking, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I have a table of data relating to some publications as follows:

```
PubID   Author
169759  ZJ
174843  RA
174843  DJ
174843  JP
174843  GS
174843  Tv
171051  MC
171051  JR
171051  CW
171719  PB
171719  MD
171719  FO
169759  FO
173847  RA
173847  DJ
```

and would like to turn this into an edgelist for input into igraph to show a co-authorship network (e.g. that RA and DJ have two papers together). I have about 7000 IDs in total. I'm ok with the network bit but I just can't work out how to get an edgelist from the data. Can you help?

Comment: Please specify which package you're using to achieve this.

Comment: I'm using R via RStudio and will be doing the network analysis using igraph. The bibliometric data comes from an in-house system in the format above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
library(igraph)


PubID <- c("169759","174843","174843","174843","174843","174843","171051","171051","171051","171719","171719","171719","169759","173847","173847")
Author <- c("ZJ","RA","DJ","JP","GS","Tv","MC","JR","CW","PB","MD","FO","FO","RA","DJ")
dt <- data.frame(Author,PubID)
levs <- unique(unlist(dt, use.names = FALSE))
adj <- table(lapply(dt, factor, levs))
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix( adj )
plot(g1)
```

[image]

I created an adjacency matrix from your data.

Comment: Yes very much like that but I don't want the pub IDs included as nodes, I just want links between the authors weighted according to how many papers they have together - is that possible without transforming the data?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on some data wrangling with tidyverse. The number of common papers between authors is stored as `n` in the edge attributes

`PubID <- c("169759","174843","174843","174843","174843","174843","171051","171051","171051","171719","171719","171719","169759","173847","173847")
Author <- c("ZJ","RA","DJ","JP","GS","Tv","MC","JR","CW","PB","MD","FO","FO","RA","DJ")
dt <- data.frame(Author,PubID)
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
dt %>%
  mutate(author_id = as.integer(Author)) -> dt
dt %>%
  inner_join(dt, by = "PubID") %>%
  filter(author_id.x < author_id.y) %>%
  count(Author.x, Author.y) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) -> g1
plot(g1)
as_data_frame(g1, what = "edges")`

[image: the resulting graph]

Comment: You probably don't need to convert author ids to integers. A little known fact is that R comparison operators work for characters (via lexicographic ordering): `"aa" < "ab"` gives `TRUE`.

Comment: In this case the authors are factors not characters. And then it doesn't work.

Comment: Sure, so just use a tibble or `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.